# Golang Godog REST API Test fails

Tags: json, rest, go, cucumber

For past 2 weeks I have been looking into GODOG, a cucumber like bdd for golang. I found it very interesting and recently I am spending more time on writing a test for my REST API(s). Recently, I am continiuosly fialing to pass one of my test. This one includes a JSON struct that has childen JSON(s) inside itself. Also I am following exact example found at following link for my test:

https://github.com/DATA-DOG/godog/tree/master/examples/api

I have a struct like:

```
type Status struct {
    ErrorCode   string  `json:"ERROR_CODE"`
    ErrorText   string  `json:"ERROR_TEXT"`
}

type OutputResponse1 struct {
    Status Status `json:"STATUS"`
}

type OutputResponse2 struct {
    Status Status `json:"STATUS"`
    Config json.RawMessage `json:"CONFIG"`
}
```

A byte type variable:

```
var responseByte []byte
```

And two different kind of output response:

```
//--------------1

responseByte, _ = json.Marshal(OutputResponse1{
    Status: Status{
        ErrorCode: "-2",
        ErrorText:  "Config was not found",
    },
})

//------------2
responseByte, _ = json.Marshal(&OutputResponseSuccess{
        Status: Status{
            ErrorCode: "0",
            ErrorText:  " ",},
        Config: json.RawMessage(body),
})
```

The `json.Rawmessage` is something coming from another source which looks like:

```
 {
      "binaryVersion":"1.0.0",
      "configVersion":"1.1.1"
 }
```

Now in feature file I have tested out something like this:

```
 //--------------1

 And the response should match json:

    {
      "STATUS": {
         "ERROR_CODE": "-2",
         "ERROR_TEXT": "Config was not found"
      }
    }
```

THIS TEST PASS

The second one being one with `json.RawMessage`

And the response should match json:

```
 {
      "STATUS": {
          "ERROR_CODE":"0",
          "ERROR_TEXT":" "
      },
      "CONFIG":{
          "binaryVersion":"1.0.0",
          "configVersion":"1.1.1"
      }
 }
```

NOW THIS ONE FAILS, EVEN THOUGH THE GODG OUTPUT HAS THE ACTUAL AND EXPECTED SAME TO SAME

```
------------------------Acutal output of godog test---------------------------

 And the response should match json:


 {"STATUS":{"ERROR_CODE":"0","ERROR_TEXT":" "},"CONFIG":      {"binaryVersion":"1.0.0","configVersion":"1.1.1"}}


 Expected json does not match actual:
 {"STATUS":{"ERROR_CODE":"0","ERROR_TEXT":" "},"CONFIG":     {"binaryVersion":"1.0.0","configVersion":"1.1.1"}}

 --- Failed scenarios:
```

Someone from the godog also advised me to get rid of leading and trailing whitespace, so I even did

```
bytes.TrimSpace(responseByte)
```

still no luck.

Anyone facing the same problem?

Comment: technically, JSON object keys are unordered, so you can't  rely on comparing them directly at all.

Comment: It really looks like there is an extra space in the middle of actual. I don't think TrimSpace helps you there

Comment: The godog test output shows that the two json strings are different, the `"CONFIG":     {"` in the actual output has one less space. This might only be in because of how you formatted the question, but if godog is comparing strings you should make sure the whitespace matches.

Comment: @mkopriva Oh I am sorry that was just my typo mistake when I copy-paste is stackoverflow. Actually config:{ is the correct one with no space at all.

Comment: @JimB Sorry Jim, I should have been more specific. The link above has an example that I am using for my test. It has the code that ignores the kv order. So basically the following passed in one of my test:

{
  "STATUS":{
      "ERROR_TEXT":"ERROR Config was not found in datastore",
      "ERROR_CODE":"-2"
  }
} 



{"STATUS":{"ERROR_CODE":"-2","ERROR_TEXT":"ERROR Config was not found in datastore"}}

Comment: @vickeyshrestha what version of Go are you running this on?

Comment: @mkopriva I am on go1.7.3

Comment: Did you try using `*json.RawMessage` as mentioned in my answer? If yes and it didn't help can you provide an example of how you compare the two values? I'm asking because the godog example, the one you've linked to, in case of a mismatch clearly shows the position of the byte that is different from the expected one, while in your example you just print the two outputs

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this will solve your issue, but if you're on Go1.7 or less then try using `*json.RawMessage` as the `Config` field's type. Because Go's pre 1.8 `json.RawMessage` had its `MarshaJSON` method defined on the pointer receiver as opposed to the value receiver which caused `json.RawMessage` values to be encoded as strings bytes in base64.

```
type OutputResponse2 struct {
    Status Status `json:"STATUS"`
    Config *json.RawMessage `json:"CONFIG"`
}

raw := json.RawMessage(body)
responseByte, err := json.Marshal(&OutputResponseSuccess{
        Status: Status{
            ErrorCode: "0",
            ErrorText:  " ",
        },
        Config: &raw,
})
if err != nil {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of **godog**. Currently in the example you linked, it compares bytes one by one and prints the actual result up to the last byte it matched.

Now about the **json.Marshal** in go. When it marshals a map to json, it [sorts map keys](https://golang.org/src/encoding/json/encode.go?s=6709:6781#L673) and having that in mind if we re-encode both expected and actual json responses, then we can be certain that it should produce the same byte slice if it matches, no matter in which order you placed expected object keys.